# Does mixed tf.keras.mixed_precision work for inference?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

I am not sure if I understand the idea of tensorflow keras [mixed precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision). My goal is to run a `tf.keras` model with floating point 16 precision to improve inference speed. Can this be done with mixed precision?

I am setting this policy before training my model:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
```

Or this is just to speed-up training. If this is the case, how could I achieve weights/activations of my tf.keras model to have FP16 precision?

*Note: I am using `tensorflow==2.3.0`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is mixed precision in training as in the link you mentioned.
Nvidia has a little bit more in depth information what that means here:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/performance/mixed-precision-training/index.html

Here is the paper describing the actual process, as well as how and why there is a copy of the FP16 weights in FP32 as master weights (therefore a mix of precisions).
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03740.pdf

But there are also mixed precision operations in hardware and these can speedup your inference when your data is FP32 and your weights/biases are in FP16, with hardware that supports mixed precision operations this can accelerate inference a lot.

For example with a Nvidia T4 i had a a speedup of ~2 on YOLO3, but no speedup on a Nvidia 1080.

Answer (score 0):

The inference of the model also gain the mixed-precision speed up.
If you want to convert a model that was trained without mixed-precision policy to take advantage of the mixed-precision mode you should:

1. Create the model with the mixed precision policy
2. load only the weights of the model.

I'll be happy to hear if someone found some other solution.